# How to make a universal pause button in Flash CS5?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to make a button in Flash that pauses all of the movie clips that are running in my file. None of these movie clips are tweens in my main timeline, they all have their own individual timeline. Each move clip is triggered by a button that tells the clips to start playing. So, if anyone could help me create this pause button, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Read [**this**](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before) first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
// create an array to store all playing movieclips 
var playing = [];

// when a movieclip is played add it to the array like this:
// playing.push(myMovieClip);

// call this from your pause button's click handler
function pauseAll() 
{
    // loop through all the playing movieclips ...
    for (var i = 0; i < playing.length; i ++)
    {
        // ... and stop them
        playing[i].stop();
    }

    // now clear the array
    playing = [];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. A little tedious to go back to all my movie clips and add each one individidually to the playing array, but it works. But, clearing the array must come outside of the for loop, otherwise it will only pause the first object of the array. Thanks though, very helpful.

Comment: Good spot! That's why you should always test kids! Updated the example.

Comment: Actually, when I run multiple movie clips at once (5 or so), I get an output: "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties." And not all of the clips pause. It also says its in the pause function. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like some of the movieclip references you're adding to the array are undefined. Try tracing each value before you add it to the array and have a look at the output. My guess is that the clips which are not pausing are all undefined at the point you add them to the array.

Comment: Well, if I am running say movie A and only movie A, it will pause. However, sometimes when I run movie B, then C, then A, A will not pause. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Found the issue... hehe. Silly mistake. When I was using copy, paste to add clips to the array, I must have missed a letter... It threw off every clip after that was clicked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Export your all symbols that you want to be paused/resumed recursively with a base class like this one, then you don't have to walk the entire display tree:

```
package com.stackoverflow
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

[Event(name="clipAdded", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Event(name="clipRemoved", type="flash.events.Event")]
public class BaseClip extends MovieClip
{
    protected var baseClipChildren:Array;
    protected var paused:Boolean = true;

    public function BaseClip()
    {
        super();
        baseClipChildren = new Array();
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        addEventListener("clipAdded", onClipAdded);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);
        addEventListener("clipRemoved", onClipRemoved);
    }

    protected function onAdded(event:Event):void
    {
        var target:BaseClip = event.target as BaseClip;
        if(target == this) {
            dispatchEvent(new Event("clipAdded", true));
        }
    }

    protected function onClipAdded(event:Event):void
    {
        var target:BaseClip = event.target as BaseClip;
        if(target && target != this) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            baseClipChildren.push(target);
        }
    }

    protected function onRemoved(event:Event):void
    {
        var target:BaseClip = event.target as BaseClip;
        if(target == this) {
            dispatchEvent(new Event("clipRemoved", true));
        }
    }

    protected function onClipRemoved(event:Event):void
    {
        var target:BaseClip = event.target as BaseClip;
        if(target && target != this) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            baseClipChildren.splice(baseClipChildren.indexOf(target),1);
        }
    }

    public function stopAll():void {
        stop();
        for each(var clip:BaseClip in baseClipChildren) {
            clip.stopAll();
        }
    }

    public function playAll():void {
        play();
        for each(var clip:BaseClip in baseClipChildren) {
            clip.playAll();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way that I know of to pause all movie clips.

If you kept a reference to movie clips that you want to pause in a globally accesible object, you could iterate through those references calling pause.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to flash, could you show me an example of what you are talking about? Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

This function will stop all nested movieClips of an object. Just pass in your stage or top-level display class to stop/play everything.  This way you don't have to keep track of adding things to an array and there's no overhead.

```
function recursiveStop(parentClip:DisplayObjectContainer, useStop:Boolean = true, gotoFrame:Object = null):void {
    var tmpClip:MovieClip = parentClip as MovieClip;
    if (tmpClip) {
        if (useStop) {
            (gotoFrame != null) ? tmpClip.gotoAndStop(gotoFrame) : tmpClip.stop();
        }else {
            (gotoFrame != null) ? tmpClip.gotoAndPlay(gotoFrame) : tmpClip.play();
        }
    }

    var i:int = parentClip.numChildren;
    while(i--){
        if(parentClip.getChildAt(i) is DisplayObjectContainer){
            recursiveStop(parentClip.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer, useStop, gotoFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just note that if you have movieClips that aren't on the display list they will be unaffected by this method.