# How do I force my flash movie to restart after using stop(); in child movie clips?

Tags: flash, loops, actionscript, movieclip

I have a flash file (a simple banner), with all the animations within child mc's. The only actionscript (2.0) I've used so far is stop(); at the end of some of the child mc's so they'll stay on the stage. This seems to stop the whole thing from looping. When I do get it to loop, none of the child mc's are at the beginning of their timelines.

Is there a way I can "reset" them all at the end of the last timeline, so that it will loop properly? Or is there a better way I could be controlling the stops?

I'm a complete AS2 noob, but have looked everywhere for the answers and haven't found anything that helps :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'reset' a movieClip timeline by calling child_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);

If you're looking to recursively stop/loop all child clips of an object (or absolutely everything), look a **my** answer to this question:  [How to make a universal pause button in Flash CS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022556/how-to-make-a-universal-pause-button-in-flash-cs5/11055990#11055990)

With that function you can reset all your clips at once by doing this:   `recursiveStop(stage,false,1);`

Comment: Thank you, I had already tried that. It loops, but when it restarts all of the child elements are at the end of their timelines.

Comment: So your saying you have a bunch of nested movieClips and you want a want to tell all of them to loop at once?

Comment: The nested mc's are staggered and all apart from the last need to stay on the stage til the last one finishes. Then they should all loop back to the beginning. I have adjusted their timelines so they now all run the same length - though I thought it could be controlled with AS? Thank you for your help :)